# Why can't get price pair (USDT/KGS, USDT/KZT) by ticker in BINANCE API?

Tags: python-3.x, binance, cryptocurrency, price, binance-api-client

`So, this is my code

```
# Import libraries
import json
import requests
  
# defining key/request url
key = "https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=USDTKGS"
  
# requesting data from url
data = requests.get(key)  
data = data.json()
print(f"{data['symbol']} price is {data['price']}")
```

But for some reason I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rate.py", line 11, in <module>
    print(f"{data['symbol']} price is {data['price']}")
KeyError: 'symbol'
```

Probably, this pair doesn't exist, but what to do in such situation?
I need to get the pair by API, but don't see any other ways to do so...
Please, help me!

I tried to use usual pairs like USDT/UAH, EUR/USDT - they work
But USDT/KGS, USDT/KZT doesn't work - they print error, but I need to get it

Comment: Please provide what print(data) will output for KTZ in your question.

Comment: Actually, its this: {"code":-1121,"msg":"Invalid symbol."}  So looks like website does not know USDTKTZ.

Comment: @bracko so how can I fix it?

Comment: When you open api in browser, without any symbol, https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price, you will see json data with all available symbols. "KGS" or "KZT" is not present there at all. So, if "KZT" and "KGS" are a valid currency codes, you have to probably change source of data, different API/website which provides data for KGS and/or KZT. As for the code, it would be wise to first check response, if it does not report an error, like this one: https://api.binance.com/api/v3/ticker/price?symbol=USDTKGS (opens in browser).

Comment: You don't fix it. There is no such trading pair on Binance (the CEX).  I guess you're tring to get KGS/USDT pair on a binance chain swap like pancake, which totally is another issue.

Comment: @halfelf thank you very much! You really helped me out! (Bracko especially)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This thing helped me

```
def fetch_price(asset: str, fiat: str, trade_type: str, pay_type: str):
    """
    Function for getting Rate on Binance P2P.
    """
    headers = {
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
        "Accept-Language": "en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8",
        "Cache-Control": "no-cache",
        "Connection": "keep-alive",
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "Host": "p2p.binance.com",
        "Origin": "https://p2p.binance.com",
        "Pragma": "no-cache",
        "TE": "Trailers",
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64; rv:88.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/88.0"
    }

    data = {
        "asset": asset,
        "fiat": fiat,
        "merchantCheck": True,
        "page": 1,
        "payTypes": [pay_type],
        "publisherType": None,
        "rows": 3,
        "tradeType": trade_type
    }

    try:
        r = requests.post('https://p2p.binance.com/bapi/c2c/v2/friendly/c2c/adv/search', headers=headers, json=data).json()

        if r['data']:
            return r['data'][2]['adv']['price']
        else:
            print(f"No data available for {asset}/{fiat}")
            return None
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
        return None
```